# Make VSCode python debug print output to terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

When debugging, vscode will not print output to terminal when `print(..)`. I try to set `"console": "externalTerminal"`,but it does not work, neither with `"console": "IntegratedTerminal"`.
I figure out why this happends, since python will not print output until it meets newline. For example,

```
print("hello", end=" ") # will not output
print("world") # will output "hello world"
```

Comment: Can you share a screenshot? VSCode already has an integrated terminal. If its not visible to you, To open the terminal (options):

1. Use the Ctrl+` keyboard shortcut with the backtick character.
2. Use the View > Terminal menu command.
3. From the Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P), use the View: Toggle Integrated Terminal command.

Answer (score 1):

To see printed outputs in your terminal, make sure that your panel is showing first off ('view' -> 'appearance' -> 'show panel').

Then check that you are viewing the right part of the panel. VSC has a 'debug console' and a 'terminal'. The 'debug console' is a place to test inputs and outputs with your code, but any print statements will be output to your terminal.

[screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRNi3.png)